# Selenium (.Net core 2) FindsBy using a custom initializer without PageFactory

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core

So I have a slightly more complicated question.

Is it possible to use the C# selenium `[FindsBy(.....)]` with some sort of custom initializer?
I know the `PageFactory` was removed and either way it would not have worked the way I would want to as what I'm interested is making the initializer do it's job at the time the element is used.

For example:

In a page object i have some locators

```cs
...

[FindsBy(How = How.Class, Using = "class1"))]
private IWebElement someElement { get; set;}

[FindsBy(How = How.Class, Using = "class2", Priority = 0))]
[FindsBy(How = How.XPATH, Using = "some_xpath", Priority = 1))]
private IWebElement someElement2 { get; set;}

...
```

Now normally with the `PageFactory` you would use the initializer in the constructor of the Page but what i'm interested is initializing these objects and doing the driver find when the element is used.

For example:

```cs
... 

//In a test or method .....
someElement2.Click() // and have this element initialized and found right here before the click and every time it is used to be re found

...
```

For this you would need to initialize or inject at least the driver beforehand, hence why I'm not sure exactly how this could be done.

Now I know you can achieve this using other methods (such as delegates) but they would not be as clean and intuitive as this and I know the PageFactory had a whole lot more features such as caching the elements but I'm not interested in that.

Comment: I’ll just point out that the PageFactory architecture did not, in fact, locate elements until the member decorated with the attribute is called. Using the `InitElements` method did _not_ execute the finds of all elements; it merely set up the plumbing to execute the find when the member of the page object class was accessed.

Answer (score 0):

```
private IWebElement someElement => WebDriver.FindElements(By.Class("class1").First();

private IWebElement someElement2 => WebDriver.FindElements(By.Class("class12").FirstOrDefault() ?? WebDriver.FindElements(By.XPath("some_xpath")).First();
```